# Evaluate the Integral: $\int\frac{e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+3e^x+2}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus

$$\int\frac{e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+3e^x+2}\mathrm{d}x$$

Step one- Factor the denominator

${e^{2x}+3e^x+2}$

$e^x\quad\quad\quad +1$ $=1e^x$

$e^x\quad\quad\quad +2$ $=2e^x$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad3e^x$

$(e^x+1)(e^x+2)$

Step two: Further Decomposition:

$\frac{A}{e^x+1}+\frac{B}{e^x+2}$

$\frac{A(e^x+2)+B(e^x+1)}{(e^x+1)(e^x+2)}$

$e^2x=A(e^x+2)+B(e^x+1)$

I am stuck at this point

The book says I should use u substitution.

Also, how is $e^{2x}=(e^x)^2$

Comment: What about $u=e^x$? You'll get a friendly rational fraction.

Comment: So is my method wrong?

Comment: What's your method? You say you are stuck.

Comment: Well I would use $e^2x=A(e^x+2)+B(e^x+1)$ and choose a number for x to get a value for A and B.

Comment: And $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$, by the way.

Comment: So any number multiplied by e  becomes e's exponent?

Comment: That's not what it means, no. Regarding your method, it would work, you'll just have to integrate at one point something like $e^x/(e^x+1)$, and the logarithm will appear here.

Comment: Are you answering my question why $e^{2x}=(e^x)^2$ If so why is the 2 in front?

Comment: This is a square. $(e^x)^2=(e^x)\times(e^x)$. And from the identity $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$, you know also that $(e^x)^2=(e^x)\times(e^x)=e^{2x}$. Beware, it's absolutely not the same as $e^{(x^2)}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $e^x=t$, we then have that $e^xdx = dt$. This gives us that
$$I=\int \dfrac{e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+3e^x+2} dx = \int \dfrac{t}{t^2+3t+2}dt = \int\dfrac{2dt}{t+2} - \int\dfrac{dt}{t+1}=2\ln(t+2)-\ln(t+1) + c$$
Hence,
$$I = 2\ln(2+e^x) - \ln(1+e^x) + c$$

Comment: Actually, there is a wrong step that does not harm: the primitive of $1/t$ is not $\log t$.